# Change header with macro in Word Template on SharePoint

Tags: templates, sharepoint, macros, header

I'm working on a Word template that the user can access from Sharepoint. 
In this template I have made a custom ribbon with custom ui editor.

I want the users to be able to choose a header and a footer.
For this I have already made 2 different headers (1 with fields and 1 without) and saved them in the template. 
So when I want to insert a header I can select them like this: Insert --> Header --> scroll all the way down to 'Template' and select one of them. This works perfect. I've recorded a Macro of this process so I am able to use this on my custom ribbon.

the macro looks like this:

```
Sub Header()
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Application.Templates( _
    "http://spf.mysite.be/Shared%20Documents/Template.dotm"). _
    BuildingBlockEntries("Header").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
     RichText:=True
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, count:=4
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```

The problem:
When I open the template from sharepoint this macro doesn't work anymore.
I think this is because Word changes the linked template. when I go to the developer tab and click on 'Document Template' the linked template is the following: 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\TemplateATA-8.dotm' (the 8 changes to a 9 the next time I open the template from SharePoint.)
When i work localy and change the link to the local location, there is no problem.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks
Nina

(I'm using Word 2013, but also older versions of Word have to be able to use the document.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I changed the link to: `Application.Templates( _
        ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName). _`
Now it works perfectly!!